# Get Raleway lining numerals for system font usage

Tags: fonts, google-webfonts, opentype

We'd like to use Raleway on our PCs but the numerals are by default jittered.  The description says it's achievable to get the lining versions that are all horizontally aligned.

I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218891/getting-different-figure-types-with-google-web-fonts) that details how to get the lining version via CSS but does anyone know how to get it in a download?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Expert mode on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator with OpenType flattening to generate a new font with lining numerals turned on.

Additionally, you could generate a font with the stylistic alts. This will give you a more modern, alternative W.

Comment: Just make sure that the font license allows derivatives, because it might not and then this might be a less than legal solution.

Comment: Raleway's license does allow modification: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/license/raleway

Comment: I know, but it's important to mention in the answer, and the SIL license has a reserved name for the font, which **may not** be used after modification. So the font can't be called "Raleway" after changing the default feature settings, as per permissions stipulation 3.

Answer (score -3):

Like turning on/off any other OpenType feature, you tell the application that you're using the font in to enable lining. If your application does not offer that control, either get a better application, or do the decent thing and get in touch with https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com, as they're people who actually *make* Raleway (which really should have been your first stop =) Just because it's a webfont doesn't mean you're automatically free to alsu use it on your desktop, although in this case, TLoMT allows that.

Comment: Not quite sure where the downvotes are coming from, when this is the technically correct answer. OpenType features are turned on or off for stretches based on engine instructions (direct commands in (Xe)LaTeX, panel menu in InDesign, etc), unless you want to generate a new font, which might be entirely against the font license