# Is there a way to specify that Android's TypeFace should use lining numbers and not old-style numbers?

Tags: android, typeface, android-typeface

I'm using Raleway, and the default is to use old-style numbers where 3, 4, 5, 7, and 9 descend below the baseline.  On iOS I can specify a feature setting to use the "upper case" (lining) numbers:

```
UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey : @(kUpperCaseNumbersSelector)
```

How do I do this on Android?

Comment: What typeface are you using? Just Roboto? Otherwise, is it an OpenType font that supports both styles?

Comment: I'm using [Raleway](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Raleway)—that is the type face.  And yes, it supports both styles.

Comment: I'll get back to you soon if no one else does. I believe this is possible natively as of API 21. It'll probably require a somewhat hacky solution for API 20 and below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, for Android 5.0 and above (API 21), you can use the fontFeatureSettings property to enable this:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setFontFeatureSettings("lnum"); // Enabling lining numbers
```

Which I've tested to work with Raleway. Unfortunately that's probably not a sufficient option. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528804/get-raleway-lining-numerals-for-system-font-usage) in which the suggested solution is to re-upload the font to FontSquirrel's [font generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and substitute the lining number glyphs for the tabular glyphs.

Comment: Looks promising.  I already have a big ol' `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` in my text handling code, so I can at least make it look good on some phones.

Comment: If you add android:fontFeatureSettings="lnum" in the xml is it backwards compatible? It does not show a warning message that it is not.

Comment: It should show a warning, but it's also most likely fine (typically, unknown attributes are ignored). One exception was that Samsung did something weird with paddingStart/paddingEnd at one point which caused a crash if you didn't do it conditionally, so there's always a possibility you'll run into issues. I'd bet on it being fine, though.