# Numbers Not on Same Line

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm new to SVG and have been putting numbers in text tags for a week or two with no issues. It seemed straightforward. Now, strangely, I'm having an issue in which, no matter what numbers I put in, there is a dip in the second number.

Here is a pic to show you what is happening. The number "63" is supposed to be all on the same plane with itself, though a bit below the "This Week" designation. Instead, the '3' is dipping down lower. [Pic of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSvVO.png).

My code:

```
   <div class = "chartbox">

        <div class = "svgcontainer" >

            <svg class = "chart"  width="590" height="440" role="img">
                <g class = "bigbox">


                    <text x="346" y = "35" class = "blurbhed">This Week </text>
                    <text x ="491" y ="44" class = "blurbdeck"><?php echo round($kms_for_table[0]);?></text><text x ="540" y ="48" class = "blurbkm"><?php echo "km";?></text>

                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {  background-color: #1C1816;

font-family: Raleway, Gotham-Rounded, Arial , sans-serif;}


.blurbhed {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: #650a5d;
    letter-spacing: .3px;


}

.blurbdeck {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: #08292e;
    letter-spacing: .4px;

}

.blurbkm {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    fill: #08292e;
    letter-spacing: .4px;

}
.svgcontainer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid purple;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 453px;
    width: 630px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 50px;

}

.chartbox {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The same problem happens wherever I move the text around the svg element. It occurs with a variety of fonts, and with different numbers. It happens whether I just have it echo the number or have it generated by the code from my model. I also tried making a completely new text element in a different spot, and the same weird dip in the second number occurs.

I'm sure this is really simple, but I've been fiddling with it far too long and am hoping someone can help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a google font by any chance...without actually seeing it in a [mcve] there's not much we can do.

Comment: Yes, it is Raleway.

Comment: After your comment asking about the font, I tried several other fonts and got different issues. Arial, Helvetica and Gotham Rounded all put the three higher than the six--so essentially the opposite problem. The rest of my code involves the rest of the svg--the background image, the bars etc. I can try to strip it down to minimal code, however, this seems to be a font issue. While I'm working on minimalizing the code, does anyone have insight into why the fonts are behaving this way? I perhaps naively thought the numbers should all be aligned no matter what font.

Comment: I've seen on SO with Raleway before....are they all webserved or hosted locally?

Comment: Web served. This is on top of my header file:  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800,600italic,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>. I could ditch the Raleway for the numbers, but I'm getting unevenness in all fonts I've tried.

Comment: It's definitely the font. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pbaAXW You could try Open Sans....that seems OK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely down to the design of the font being used.."Raleway".

[image]

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1>0123456789</h1>


<h2>0123456789</h2>
```

I can only suggest using a different font..but you'd have to test each for the right look.

Comment: Thank you @Paulie. Yep, it's the font. Oddly, Open Sans causes the 3 to be higher for me, however, I did find two or three fonts which at least for this number give me an even result.  In case anyone wants to know, Montserrat, Lato and source Sans Pro gave me 'even' numbers in this example; most of the other fonts I tried didn't. i'm new to design and a little puzzled as to why anyone would design a font in which the numbers don't look right when placed next to each other. But anyway, I've learned that this is a font-fiddle thing, so thank you!

Comment: Correction to above for anyone browsing this--Open Sans does in fact give evenly placed numbers. I tried it again. I think when I did the earlier test I must have not refreshed my browser from the test before it.

Comment: That font's using text figures, aka 'old style'.  It's quite common and some fonts support various styles of numeral, which can be controlled using CSS `font-feature-settings` using vales like `onum` or `tnum` to choose old-style or tabular style respectively.

Comment: Thank you @searlea. Yes, I have since discovered that the numbers that look even when used side by side are called "lining figures," which is the opposite of the "old style" you mention." I see from your post that 'tabular' style is another name for them.  I've tried the font feature settings, such as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218891/getting-different-figure-types-with-google-web-fonts), and haven't had any luck yet in making them work in Chrome or Safari. I'll probably keep fiddling with it.

Answer (score 6):

There's a proper solution for this that allows you to continue using Raleway:

You need to do two things:

1. Add CSS instructing the browser to use the lining-figures
2. Avoid pre-optimised font files (as served by Google Fonts.)

The CSS:

```
body {
    font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
    font-feature-settings: "lnum";
}
```

Alternative CDN ([Brick](http://brick.im/)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//brick.a.ssl.fastly.net/Raleway:400">
```

The problem with Google Fonts is that it minimises font download size by removing 'unnecessary' glyphs and meta-data.  In particular in this case, it removes the lining-nums variation of figures from Raleway.  (You can try adding `&subset=all` to a Google Font URL to circumvent this, but this doesn't appear to be reliable.)

Comment: Thank you, @searlea! That worked great, and it's interesting to know that Google fonts are removing some data from the font. The one thing that is very strange is that if I try to apply 'Raleway' globally in the body element of my css, I continue to get the old style figures even with your fix. The only way your code above works for me is if I remove the font family from the body and apply it to each element. That's an okay workaround for me, but still I wonder why. I couldn't believe it was really true, so I tried it three times, with the same result.