# webfont has incorrect kerning in IE10, IE11

Tags: css, webfonts, text-rendering, kerning

I am working on a project for a client that uses a custom created webfont.  The webfont displays with correct kerning in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera when I implement the following styles:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-feature-settings: "kern";
```

In IE10/IE11, the font does not display with correct kerning with or without the above styles.  I have tried a variety of options without success.  Per MDN, the font-feature-settings property is supported in IE10+.  In fact, when I inspect I can see that the font-feature-settings: kern -- being applied but there is no change to the kerning.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a sample/code share of your issue? What have you tried already? Help us help you :) -- Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160897/font-feature-settings-what-is-the-correct-syntax

Comment: Hi @BJack, I actually have checked out that comment and none of the examples/suggestions rectified my issue.  I have tried using the font-feature-settings with and without the -ms prefix as well.  Unfortunately, I have an NDA signed with the client so I won't be able to share the code/font via a codepen or js fiddle.  I can however provide screenshots of the differences in each browser.  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [demo page](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/opentype/opentype-fontbureau/index.html) on this subject shows a different syntax than you're using:

```
/* enable kerning data */ 
.kerning { 
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
   -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern=1"; 
   -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; 
}
```

Note two MS-specific differences:

1. The `font-feature-settings` property has a `-ms-` prefix.
2. The value `"kern"` is followed by a space and a value before the semicolon.

Comment: @quietqake, I was able to try that syntax prior to asking for assistance with the issue.  Unfortunately, in both IE10 and IE11 adding that prefix does nothing for my situation.

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark without your code, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh869409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx suggests removing the prefix but using the value after "kern". So the second line of code in your question would be font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; (or whatever value you want).

Comment: thanks for the feedback.   I have tried those options as well.  I visited the demo page in IE and inspected the kerning values and toggled them on and off to visibly see the difference.  When I use that same technique on my page with the custom font, no such behavior occurs.  At this point I am beginning to think it is attributed to an issue at the font level that may not be cured with pure css.

Comment: You were able to set kerning on this font in other browsers though, right? Each of these font customization aspects must be supported by the target font, so if it doesn't work in any browser, that suggests that the font you're using doesn't support kern.

Comment: yes I was able to get it working in Chrome/Safari and Firefox.  IE and specifically IE10/IE11, the versions of IE where font-feature-settings are supported, is where it still does not work.

Comment: What a puzzle! Are you using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge" /> in the document head? If IE is opening your page in compatibility mode, this meta element should prevent that.