# Which feature to test in IE/Edge font support?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, microsoft-edge, webfonts

For an online demo (project) I wosh to pretend an LCD display. I found a fine 7segment font https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/segment7 . One of it's fetures is that the decimal dot uses some kind of "negative kerning" (or letter-spacing, please apologize my lack of terminology), so it visually belongs to previous number. This is desired behaviour.

However, this behaviour works only in FF & Chrome, not in Edge/IE ( 
see https://jsfiddle.net/jan_koupil/o1c8srt1/2/)

```
@import url(//fontlibrary.org/face/segment7);
#display {
  font-family: 'Segment7Standard', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px 5px 1px;
  width: 142px;
  text-align: right;
}
…
<div id="display">8.8.8.8.8.8.8.8.</div>
```

For these browsers I need to switch the font to a different variant or at least reduce font size in order to fit into the fixed size display DIV. My trouble is that everybody recommends testing features, not browser versions but I don't know which feature to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to missing kerning in Internet Explorer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005821/999162) on how to explicitly add kerning to the text rendering for IE. You might also check other Opentype features and how they are activated via CSS.

Comment: thank you, the explicit addition of kerning helps. However, in general I am still unsure, how to test support and degrade gracefully.