# How to find out which `font-feature-settings` safe web fonts (Arial, Georgia, Tahoma) / any font do support?

Tags: css, fonts

I tried to implement CSS3 [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) lining [figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures), in particular with Georgia (Windows 7, OpenType), but Georgia* does seem to just support oldstyle figures.

Widest supported syntax, originating from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161336/1696030

```css
.ffs--lnum {
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum=1"; /* Fx 4 to 14 */
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum";   /* Fx 15 onwards */
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum" 1; /* Fx 15 onwards explicitly set feature values */
            font-feature-settings: "lnum";   /* other features for comparison: c2sc=1, smcp=1 */
    font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
}
```

Here's also a [Codepen including my attempts](http://codepen.io/Volker_E/pen/eNEjMm) so far.

**How can I find out which `font-feature-settings` a certain font (web safe/webfont) is supporting without trial and error?** Are there certain applications that show those? I don't necessarily care about platforms, all inputs are welcome.

**Edit (*)**: Georgia's installed in v. 5.00, and as much as it's an interesting note, it is not the main topic of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: the CSS "web safe" fonts make no assurances whatsoever about which *versions* of those fonts get used. Two versions of Georgia or Arial, ten years apart, can be rather different beasts. CSS default families (both the web safe fonts and the generic family categories) are not meant for when you need to control the typesetting of your content, rather they're for when you *don't* care about typesetting but just need the text broadly styled in a way that will at least work cross-platform and cross-browser.

If you *do* care about controlling the typesetting, which you clearly do: use an actual font. Use something like Typekit, or host your own version of the exact font you need, and then link to that with a `@font-face` rule, with the guaranteed assurance that the font is going to support exactly the features you need for typesetting.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your input. I'm fully aware, that those can be (a lil) 'different beasts'. Although from my experience a professional typographer won't change a font radically, but fixing small glitches and adding more characters.
But so can fonts who you're including via Google Fonts either. Saying a priori that a web font is better than a font like Georgia isn't true for me. My question remains, are there helper apps, which can provide me the `font-feature-settings` of any font thrown at them?

Comment: It's essentially true for everyone: if you absolutely care about the opentype features, the only way to *guarantee* that everyone on your site uses the same font is to give them the font to load. And if you care about the features, I would recommend against a google webfont, because those can be updated whenever google wants, invalidating your use. You want to serve a font *pegged at a specific version*. As for finding the font features in fonts: if you use `Georgia` you don't *get* a font. You can't load the font the browser picks for that font family into a JS context, for instance.